# Ajax/Magnific-PopUp switching content within a popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, magnific-popup

I'm having difficulty with Magnific-popup and its AJAX. I want to simply switch the content of a popup if the link is also a popup. This should work by default, but somehow it doesn't.

**JavaScript**:

```
$('.magnific').magnificPopup({
   type: 'ajax',
   ajax: {
    settings: null, 
    cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur',
    tError: '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.'
   },
   closeOnContentClick: false,
   closeOnBgClick: true,
   showCloseBtn: false,
   mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
   callbacks: {
     parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('.overlay');
            console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
     },
     ajaxContentAdded: function() {
        console.log(this.content);
     }
  }
});
```

This works with a link on the standard site. But if there is a link within the popup, it just executes that link, ignoring the Magnific Popup.

My best guess is, that it cant initiate itself because it cant find the selector (like if you use `.click` instead of `.on('click'...))`, but I don't seem to figure it out on my own.

Any help would be VERY! apprechiated!

**EDIT**: Ok I have identified the problem. It seems that the code in functions.js is not available at all within the limits of a popup. Is there a way to make the .js file available in the popup? The only way I made it work is by including the .js file in every file that has a magnific link... but that seems really dirty. Should I load it with the ajax callback or is there another way?

Best regards,
G

Comment: for JavaScript or CSS, you need to put the `<script>` or `<link>` inside the popup, otherwise it won't be available.
And what do you mean with: "if the link is also a popup"

Comment: My solution was loading the script in the AJAX `:success` callback with `$.getScript('');` The problem I encountered is a standard JQuery/AJAX "feature". They don't load `<script>` tags when processing AJAX calls because apparently they want to prevent you from dobule loading. My problem with this "feature" is, that they don't give you an option to enable/disable it and force you to do something you don't want to.